# How to log all Active Directory LDAP queries?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ldap

I want to debug the Windows Server 2008's LDAP and see all the LDAP search details, so I edit the `Field Engineering` key to 5 in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NTDS\Diagnostics` registry entry, but in the event viewer, the "Field Engineering" log doesn't show up, anyone has some clue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer.
Just change **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NTDS\Expensive Search Results Threshold** and **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NTDS\Inefficient Search Results** Threshold to 1, then I can see all the LDAP search details.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms808539.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#efficientadapps_topic04, this article explains it.